# Overwriting Datetime is not working in Postgresql in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

So what I need to do is to change few rows in a model DateTime field to 40 days in the past, with Django using a PostgreSQL database. Where I choose all products with an even ID and change the `date_uploaded` value.

This is what I am currently doing...

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from store.models import Product
import datetime

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        all_products = Product.objects.all()
        for product in all_products:
            if product.pk % 2 == 0:
                product.date_uploaded = product.date_uploaded - datetime.timedelta(40,2,0,0)
                product.save()                
                print(product.date_uploaded)
```

And for some reason when I try to save the product it works with no errors but the DateTime value is not changed. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

this is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", default="https://eblossomsl.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/logo.png")
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images", blank=True)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=20, default="HRT", db_index=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    search_query = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now())
    quantity_bought = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `auto_now` argument passed into `DateTimeField`, this argument is responsible for changing the value of the field to the current datetime each time `.save()` is called on the object, i.e. every time you are running your script it sets it to current datetime and your changes are ignored. What you really need is `auto_now_add` which sets the value only once at the object creation.

```
date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
```

Run `makemigrations`, apply them and run your script again.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense, but then after doing the alternations can I once again make it `auto_now`? Would there be a problem with that?

Comment: of course you can, but why don't you declare a separate field for this, like `date_updated`? i.e. `date_uploaded` would be `auto_now_add`, whereas `date_updated` would be `auto_now`

Comment: And actually, you don't need to pass the current datetime neither to `auto_now` nor `auto_now_add`, you can pass a boolean value `True`

Comment: ooooo lala, makes perfect sense now